# Prevent Ruby On Rails Automatic Parameter Downcasing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a strange problem on Rails 3.2 that I haven't been able to nail down. I'm obfuscating parameters for a given resource to provide some basic access security (this isn't sensitive data, we just want to make sure that a guest user gets to a certain place deliberately and can't enter in other ids). To do this, I overloaded the `to_param` method of one of my models.

```
def to_param
  encrypt id
end
```

The `encrypt` method returns a Base64 hash. Example: `Xa_bVjBh1zZUQ2fqlNb4tA==`

When I call the model's path helpers, the URL gets constructed correctly, but both `params[:id]` and `request.url` are lowercasing the hash! This is causing headaches, as you might imagine.

Contextual examples:

```
object.to_param # Xa_bVjBh1zZUQ2fqlNb4tA==

params[:id] # xa_bvjbh1zzuq2fqlnb4ta==

request.url # http://localhost:3000/objects/xa_bvjbh1zzuq2fqlnb4ta==

object_path(id: Object.last.to_param) # "/objects/Xa_bVjBh1zZUQ2fqlNb4tA=="
```

Can anyone provide insight on why this may be occurring?

Answer (score 0):

May want to check and see if someone else on your team implemented something to automatically downcase to_params, in order to make urls case insensitive. I feel like that isn't default behavior.